# How to call function by reference?

Tags: ubercart

I want to call `uc_stock` module by reference in my custom module. Actually I want to add and delete stocks. I have done this first using node_presave and it works successfully, here is the code:

---

```
function my_module_node_presave($node){
  if($node->type == 'add_stock') {
    //drupal_set_message('stock_save :'.print_r($node,true));
    //drupal_set_message($node->field_reference['und'][0]['nid']);
    //$nid=16;
    //$p_node = node_load($nid);
    //drupal_set_message($p_node->field_product_stock['und'][0]['value']);
    $product = $node->field_stock_value['und'][0]['value'];
    drupal_set_message('product :'.$product);
    $nid = $node->field_reference['und'][0]['nid'];
    drupal_set_message('nid :'.$nid);
    $p_node = node_load($nid);
    $stock = $p_node->field_product_stock['und'][0]['value'];
    drupal_set_message('stock :'.$stock);

    $stock = $product + $stock;
    drupal_set_message('Stock :'.$stock);
    $p_node->field_product_stock['und'][0]['value'] = $stock;
    //$p_node = node_load($nid);

    //drupal_set_message($p_node);
   // drupal_set_message('node_load :'.print_r($p_node,true));

    node_save($p_node);
    //drupal_set_message('after saving product');
  }
 elseif($node->type == 'sold_stock') {
   $new_product = $node->field_sold_stock['und'][0]['value'];
   drupal_set_message('new product :'.$new_product);
  $new_nid = $node->field_stock_reference['und'][0]['nid'];
   drupal_set_message('new nid :'.$new_nid);
   $new_node = node_load($new_nid);
  $sold_product = $new_node->field_product_stock['und'][0]['value'];
   drupal_set_message('sold product :'.$sold_product);
   $product_sold = $sold_product - $new_product;
   drupal_set_message('product sold :'.$product_sold);
   $new_node->field_product_stock['und'][0]['value'] = $product_sold;
   node_save($new_node);
 }
}
```

---

Now I want to do the same thing as done in `uc_stock` module of [Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart).

Comment: Anyone? can suggest something??

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but if you want to change the stock for a product you can simply call the `uc_stock_set()` function (where the product is in the $node variable, and the new stock is in the $stock variable)

```
$stock = 5;
uc_stock_set($node->model, $stock); // sets stock to 5
```

Or use `uc_stock_adjust()` to increase or decrease the stock by a certain amount

```
uc_stock_adjust($node->model, 1); // adds 1 to current stock, stock is now 6
```

---

I am assuming that you have

- Installed ubercart
- Activated the uc_stock module
- Created a product, and set its SKU (model) to a certain value, say MODEL_1
- Gone to the 'stock' tab on the edit node page of this product and activated the stock for MODEL_1

At this point we have a product, represented by a node. This product has one (or many) associated SKUs. Each SKU has an associated stock stored in the database by uc_stock.

Only once all of this is in place can we can go ahead and use the `uc_stock_set` and `uc_stock_adjust` functions.

Comment: thanks penten for replying to my question. yes iam using uc_stock_adjust() like this:uc_stock_adjust($sku, $qty, $check_active = TRUE); ut it gives error of undefined variable

Comment: and one more thing, what do you mean by $node->mode in uc_stock_adjust($node->mode, 1);?

Comment: You have to pass the SKU of the product along with a variable containing the stock for that model.
(I'm afraid I misspelt model as mode in the second example, updated)

Comment: can you help me with the code to pass the SKU of the product along with a variable containing the stock for the model. Actually im new to drupal.

Comment: I have updated my answer. If you have a product node, the SKU (model) will be $node->model. The stock you want to set for this product will depend on what you're trying to do.

Comment: function my_module_node_presave($node){
    
  if($node->type == 'add_stock') {
    $stock_value = $node->field_stock_value['und'][0]['value'];
 
 $sku = $node->field_sku['und'][0]['value'];
 
 if (module_exists('uc_stock') && function_exists('uc_stock_adjust')) {
    
 uc_stock_adjust($sku, $stock_value, $check_active = TRUE);
 
   
   
 }
  }
 
 
}. This is my code. Now what next i should do?

Comment: `uc_stock_adjust($sku, $stock_value);`

Comment: yes i have done that. But my real question is still der. This does not do any addition or subtraction in the stock value of product node

Comment: Are you sure you are passing a valid $sku, and that $stock_value is not 0? If so, it will update the stock in the database.

Comment: i had 3 content types:one named new_product with fields: field_product_stock,second named add_stock with fields: field_stock_value,fiel_reference and field_sku and third is sold stock with fields same as second one.

Comment: yes it is a valid value as i checked it by using drupal_set_meassage. and it is printing the value

Comment: And are you sure that the sku is valid? If you go to the product page and check the stock tab, is the sku you are using present there?

Comment: no. how to make this possible. I think its very basic and stupid question too. But please help my code is not working at all

Comment: do yo want to say that i should add a sku field to product type also?

Comment: penten are you there?

Comment: I have updated my question with details on how to install ubercart and activate the stock module. As long as all the conditions I listed are filled, the functions will work correctly. If they don't work correctly right now, it's because the SKU you are providing them is invalid - it doesn't exist in the database - because no product with that SKU has been created.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7252/discussion-between-penten-and-aashi)

Comment: yes that is true.So how to save a product with a SKU in database

Comment: hey anybody can help me out with this